# Facebook/twitter/linkedin posts tracking from ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, twitter, analytics, social-networking

I have a web app that allows users to post on social networking sites.I need to track the posts posted from my app like their likes, shares, views, etc.

I understand that twitter has its own analytics dashboard where we can view all tweets analytics, but i am not sure how to pull the data. And more specifically i am looking for stats on posts made from my app on these sites.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: you can use a gem https://github.com/sferik/twitter

Comment: @RajarshiDas Thank you for your answer, but what i am looking for is stats about the posts people would post from my app. This is more like implementing the twitter gem for how to post, share, search, friends list, timeline.